# Caliper error Use microbenchmark instrument

Tags: microbenchmark, caliper

I don't seem to be able to get started here.
I pulled down the code and built caliper myself, which solved my first set of problems, but now I am getting errors that I need a microinstrument

> This experiment requires a microbenchmark. The granularity of the timer (535ns) is greater than 0.1% of the measured runtime (331.0μs). Use the microbenchmark instrument for accurate measurements.

so, how do I set the micro instrument?

I'm using @Benchmark before the method I want to run, and inside my main looks like this:

```
CaliperMain.main(
    MyClass.class,
    new String[]{ "-i", "runtime" }
);
```

I tried changing runtime to "micro", but that didn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, all you need is to use

```
@Benchmark int time(int reps) {
    // repeat reps times what you want to measure
}
```

instead of

```
@Benchmark int time() {
}
```